# OnListItemClick Shift from one ListFragement to Another using fragment Transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list fragment from where when any list item is clicked, I want to move to another list fragement.
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Schedule extends ListFragment{
....
....
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
....
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
DailyList fragment = new DailyList();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list_fragment, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

}

This is the new class that I am trying to move to.

```
public class DailyList extends ListFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day, container, false);
    return theInflatedView;
}
....
....
....
}
```

I tried using v4 android support libraries. but the replace call is giving me this error "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, DailyList)".

I read few other answers that asked to use v4. That is what I am doing. But still getting error. Please help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing newer fragment support types with support classes. Replace these lines:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

import android.app.FragmentManager;

with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Then extend

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

instead of

```
Activity
```

and change calls like

```
getFragmentManager()
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

and similarly for other methods that you might be using.

Comment: If you look at my imports you can see I am importing only v4 supports classes

Comment: change calls like 

getFragmentManager()
 with 

getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I tried that. but still the sam issue. Can you tell me in which xml R.id.list_fragment this is to be put?

Comment: this need to be a part of the activity's xml

Comment: but my main activity xml is a pager. It is not letting my add fragment